# How to add pages to an existing excel spreadsheet with python

Tags: python, excel, append, addition, openpyxl

So I have tried multiple things to add pages to an existing excel spreadsheet, but I can't find anything that works. This is the code that creates the original sheet.

```
writer = ExcelWriter('test3.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Playoffs')
sec.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Second Round')
cf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Conference Finals')
cham.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Finals')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Stanley Cup Winner')

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

For some reason when I try to run this again and add different sheets to the file, it says "permission denied" to the file.

Here is something I tried with openpyxl which did not work.

```
import openpyxl
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 
 path = 'test3.xlsx'
 
 with pd.ExcelWriter(path) as writer:
     writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
     pdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='new_sheet2'
```

And here is another segment I tried that came with the error "Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!"

```
with ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

Let me know if you how to do this, I have searched everywhere and nothing seems to work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `openpyxl`'s `create_sheet` function:

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
wb.create_sheet("SheetName")
```